# Emacs not responding to keystrokes

Tags: macos, terminal, emacs

I installed emacs using

- brew install --cask emacs

when I launch Emacs from the terminal with

- emacs

None of the keystrokes respond in emacs and all show up in the terminal window.

**Step by step:**

1. open terminal enter emacs -Q (expect emacs to launch), emacs launches
2. enter Emacs buffer, blinking cursor shows, enter text using keyboard (expect text to show on buffer and use emacs commands), text shows in terminal
3. open chrome, try to open buffer expect to be able to open emacs buffer ->can't switch to emacs buffer
4. minimize chrome then select emacs buffer window expect to be able to select buffer, cursor to blink and be able to type in buffer -> no type comes out, error audible occurs and no text in terminal.
5. Switch to terminal FIRST, then buffer loops back to step 2

**I'm running:**

- Macbook pro m3 max
- Sonoma 14.1 (23B2073)

Never had this problem when emacs was previously installed on my macs.

** update
downloaded the Emacs app and do not have this problem updated my .zshrc file to load the emacs app.

- trying to figure out how to create a new org file from terminal now

*** solved
downloaded the emacs app from the website and added the first sections of https://emacsformacosx.com/tips

thanks all

Comment: Please provide a step-by-step recipe to repro the problem, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). Say what you see and what you expected to see, at each step.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my post with a step by step and expectations as you suggest. It helped identify something weird in that it seems that when I try to switch from a different application back to the buffer I can't. I have to go to terminal first then to the buffer. It's telling me that the terminal window is activating and not the buffer window.

Comment: Thank you; much clearer. Not sure the question is really about Emacs, but maybe someone will be able to help.

Comment: I don't suppose it was opening X11 emacs, with cursor blinking in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

*** solved downloaded the emacs app from the website and added the first sections of https://emacsformacosx.com/tips